# In Azure pipeline linux commands getting truncated at the end of the script file

Tags: bash, azure, curl, pipeline, elastic-stack

I am running an azure devops pipeline to install and configure ELK. So there is a shell script which executes all the commands to install ELK and configure using curl commands. But at the end of the file last 4-5 commands are not executed and I can see truncated scripts in the log.

```
2020-06-12T08:56:10.2856017Z > echo "Registering the azure reposi
2020-06-12T08:56:10.2856671Z > curl -X PUT -uadmin:"***" "https://10.XXX.X
2020-06-12T08:56:10.2856981Z > echo "Setting up snapshot backup poli
2020-06-12T08:56:10.2857523Z > curl -X PUT -uadmin:"***"  https:
2020-06-12T08:56:10.2857807Z > echo "Finished configuring Kibana"
```

I have also swaped these scripts  with other scripts above it which were executed successfully but again the scripts which were successfull now starts getting truncated. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have the answer but I was able to resovle this issue by moving all the curl commands in a bash script file and executed it.